# CORS blocks bootsrap from one dev serv to another

Tags: laravel, cors

I have my prod server (domain.example) and 4 dev servs (domain-dev1.example, domain-dev2.example...)

When i load dev1, everything's fine, but when I want to open dev2 on another tab, the CSS file is blocked by CORS :

Access to CSS stylesheet at 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' from origin 'https://domain-dev2.example' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://domain-dev1.example' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

When I Shift+F5 cors allows it, but going back to dev1 would now have the same problem the other way around.

I'm using Laravel 5.5, is there some type of middleware I should add somewhere ?

The CSS file is loaded on my app.blade.php like so :

`<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="xxx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="xxx" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: How are you loading this stylesheet? It looks like the browser is trying to retrieve it from cache but the cached response has the previous origin in it

Comment: I edited the question to answer you

Comment: Try removing `crossorigin="anonymous"`